# TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'userId'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So i was implementing a users model in my mvc and then i get a weird error saying

```js
MongoClient constructor.
D:\node\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2022
    if (path in this.$__.selected) {
             ^

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'email' in saifkhan501721@gmail.com
    at model.isSelected (D:\node\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\document.js:2022:14)
    at D:\node\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\document.js:2195:14
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at _getPathsToValidate (D:\node\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\document.js:2194:71)
    at model.Document.$__validate (D:\node\node_modules\←[4mmongoose←[24m\lib\document.js:2365:23)
    at D:\node\node_modules\←[4mkareem←[24m\index.js:369:33
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)←[39m
```

i have no idea as to what is the reason behind the error is, is it a syntax error , logical error connection error or mispelling of a variable,well anyway here's my app.js

```js
mongoose
  .connect('mongodb+srv://turd_waffle:SaifKhan@cluster0.lltqs.mongodb.net/shop?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
  .then((result) => {
    User.findOne().then(user=>{
      if(!user){
        const user=new User({
          name:'Saif',
          email:'saifkhan501721@gmail.com',
          cart:{
            items:[]
          }
        })
        user.save()
      }
    })//save() saves the documents(mostly used as a reference to generate a sample id in order to start a cluster working)
    app.listen(3000)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

here's my user.js model to store users data in mongodb database

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  cart: {
    items: [{
      productId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product',
        required: true
      },
      quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    }]
  },
})

userSchema.methods.addToCart = function(product) {
  const cartProductIndex =  this.cart.items.findIndex(cp => {
    return cp.productId.toString() === product._id.toString();
  })
  let newQuantity = 1;
  const updatedCartItems = [...this.cart.items];
  if (cartProductIndex >= 0) {
    newQuantity = this.cart.items[cartProductIndex].quantity + 1;
    updatedCartItems[cartProductIndex].quantity = newQuantity
  } else {
    updatedCartItems.push({
      productId: product._id,
      quantity: newQuantity
    })
  }
  const updatedCart = {
    items: updatedCartItems
  }
  this.cart=updatedCart
  return this.save()
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

can anyone please be kind enough to atleast tell me what the error above is trying to say i used app.use to create a user so i can store his id, email and name

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  User.findById('5f788c080ba19e0f8c642202')
    .then(user => {
      req.user = new User(user.name, user.email, user.cart, user._id);
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: The right-hand side of an `in` expression must be an object. In your case, it's a string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I get a type error in Firefox from `"foo" in "bar"`

Comment: You can tell it's a runtime error (so not a JavaScript syntax error) because there's a stack trace. What line of **your** code does the error occur on?

Comment: @Pointy - Hey, so do I in V8 in Chrome. Wow. I always thought `in` coerced! Off to read the spec... :-)

Comment: @Pointy i use google chrome so browser support isnt the issue here

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i guess at the app.js file in the email section

Comment: @SaifullahKhan - Pointy wasn't saying it's browser related.

Comment: @Pointy - Sure enough, "If Type(rval) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception." Wow. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange issue. From the code you provided, the issue should not arise.
When I look at the code in mongoose, the only way that this could happen is if you would do something like:

`new User("saifkhan501721@gmail.com")`

Then `this.$__.selected` would be a string instead of an object (e.g. {email: "saifkhan501721@gmail.com"}) and `path in this.$__.selected` would cause your received type error.

Not knowing enough about your app, I would assume that there maybe is a bad User object created somewhere else / cached / or already in database. Maybe it would help to verify this using a clean database?

See the [source code for reference](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L2023). When I take a look at the code it seems like an oversight that it is not checked if `this.$__.selected` is a string, because in this case it does not fail early (e.g. `Object.keys(this.$__.selected)` will not cause an error).

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to all this will anyone be kind enough to comment and explain what this.$__.selected is supposed to be in mongoose

Comment: It's an internal implementation detail, so you don't have to worry about it too much.
It normally contains the fields of the document, e.g. in your case email and name. However when you run your app, it is filled with a string (your email). This makes it likely that mongoose tries to load a user just with a single string, instead of the fields. Have you tried running your app with a clean database or searching for a call in your code like `new User("saifkhan501721@gmail.com")`? Maybe this happened when you were playing around with mongoose.

Comment: This is what I would propose because it seems to be the most promising solution (assuming that you don't have any relevant data in the dabase of course).

Comment: hey pal turns out you were right i deleted the entire database and restarted with a fresh new database and it worked